# MS Excel Power Query DateAdd Now()

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

Can anyone tell me how to adjust the Power Query syntax below, so that it filters all records where [Status] <> complete AND [Finish Date] is before today plus 10 days?

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="GlobalLegalTable"]}[Content],
#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({Source, GCMT, GPMT, GSOLUTIONT, GINTEGRATIONT, GINTELLIREACHT, GCONFIGT, GDATAT, GREPORTINGT, GSUPPLIERT, LCMT, LLEGALT, LDATAT, LCONFIGT, LFINANCET, LPMT, LTRAININGT, LWORKERT, LSUPPLIERT, LOPST}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Appended Query", each ([Status] <> "Complete")),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Finish Date] <= DateTime.FixedLocalNow) in
#"Filtered Rows1"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Got it -

## "Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Finish Date] < Date.AddDays(DateTime.FixedLocalNow(), 14))